# Ruby PStore vs Marshal performance

Tags: ruby, marshalling

I am trying to decide whether to implement a `PStore` in my code instead of saving the various objects as `Marshal`.
The following code attempts to compare the performance of the two approaches:

```
require 'pstore'

def m_dump(filename, object)
    File.open(filename,"wb") do |f|
        Marshal.dump(object, f)
    end
end

def m_load(filename)
    object = nil
    File.open(filename,'rb') do |f|
        object = Marshal.load(f)
    end
    return object
end

test = {}
test[:pi] = [Math::PI]*100000000

start = Time.now
m_dump("test.marshal", test);nil
puts "Marshal File written in #{(Time.now - start).to_s}"

start = Time.now
results = PStore.new("test.pstore")
results.transaction{results[:test] = test};nil
puts "Pstore File written in #{(Time.now - start).to_s}"

start = Time.now
test2 = m_load("test.marshal");nil
puts "Marshal File read in #{(Time.now - start).to_s}"

start = Time.now
results2 = PStore.new("test.pstore")
test3 = results2.transaction{results2[:test]};nil
puts "Pstore read in #{(Time.now - start).to_s}"

puts "Marshal check #{test2 == test}"
puts "Pstore check #{test3 == test}"
```

Running the code produces the following results:

```
Marshal File written in 7.936485
Pstore File written in 5.526494
Marshal File read in 5.890848
Pstore read in 11.135965
```

It seems that `PStore` is slightly faster when a new archive is created, but much slower when data has to be read.

Given that `PStore` is based on `Marshal` anyway, I would expect similar performance. Is this behaviour to be expected?

Comment: Also check out the OX gem if you're concerned about speed.  http://www.ohler.com/dev/ruby_object_xml_serialization/ruby_object_xml_serialization.html

Comment: it's be good to compare the update time for files of different sizes, since hashes are commonly stored.

Answer (score 0):

transaction => transaction(true)
where "true" means readonly. Then the performance will be similar with marshall.

```
start = Time.now
results2 = PStore.new("test.pstore")
test3 = results2.transaction(true) {results2[:test]}; nil
puts "Pstore read in #{(Time.now - start).to_s}"
```